# how to create a shutdown button using PHP to shutdown the computer?

Tags: php, linux, button, shutdown, system-shutdown

Is possible to create a shutdown button in PHP to shutdown the computer that using Linux Debian Operating System?

Answer (score 3):

I suppose it is possible if you want to give such system permission to the user PHP is running as in your web server.  This would be a terrible design from a security standpoint.

Comment: And if you did that terrible design, the php code for it would be `<?php shell_exec('shutdown'); ?>`

Comment: On my machine, shutdown requires a parameter, like `shutdown now` or `shutdown +1` (for one minute). Not that anybody's really going to do this, I hope.

Comment: you can use `poweroff` as a shorthand for `shutdown -h now`. however, terrible idea indeed.

Comment: i just using localhost for running php.